# How can i solve this problem, there appears somthing yello and red (Error range)

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i solve this problem, there appears somthing yello and red[image: the image describes the problem]

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet? It seems like that you access an index of your list, but it is out of the range e.g. your list has a length of 2 but you access the index 5.

Comment: Can you join me in a zoom meeting please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Range index error.

-> Error thrown due to a value being outside a valid range.

if you are using listview builder you have to check your list length and item count length is the same or not.

Check this:-

Example:-
[image]

if this is not working Please describe your code.

More information about Range Class. [Click Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RangeError-class.html)

Comment: Can you join me in a zoom meeting please?

Comment: sorry for that i am busy with my team. But you can add your code on git hub and I solved it when I am free.